# Rudin 8.4 What is the purpose of this theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis

What is the significance of Rudin 8.4? If I already have some power series that converges inside some radius, what is the purpose of coming up with another series which converges inside that original radius for an even smaller interval? I am sure there is something more nuanced here that I am missing. How is this used to approximate functions when I could simply use the original power series which converges for the same radius and more?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You appear to be missing that it’s not just the radius that changes: it’s the point around which the function is expanded. The point of the theorem is that if you know the expansion of $f$ in some interval around a certain point, you can deduce the expansion of $f$ around **any other point** in that interval (on a sufficiently small region).

Comment: @symplectomorphic would I then use this other expansion to approximate the function around that point?

Comment: One thing that it shows is that the property of being analytic is open. Compare to being differentiable or continuous. A function can be continuous or differentiable at a point, but it might not be at nearby points. It also quantifies at least how far to expect the nearby series to converge.

Comment: A very simple application is that you now know $f$ is infinitely differentiable in its radius of convergence. Without this theorem, you only know a priori that $f$ has power series expansion at a single point (and thus only infinitely differentiable there).

Comment: @TeslaDaybreak: That is actually quite a nice point. My first reaction was "Well, if $f$ is twice differentiable at a point, then it is differentiable in a neighbourhood and so on... So it must be infinitely differentiable on a neighbourhood". But then I realised that the neighbourhoods could keep getting smaller. [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3393040/) shows that that is indeed possible.